# Load detected on my server at certain time

Tags: linux, load

[image]

On certain time in the night, facing load for 3 to 4 minutes. Sometimes it takes more also. I have checked all log files, visitors at that time also, but this happens when I don't have much users visiting the site. I don't have database more than 50MB right now, so it should not be mysql issue. If it is due to some code issue, like looping etc so then it should also appear at the time when I have users on the site.  Time when I have users on my site, load is not detected. I have searched analyzed alot on this issue, but from last weeks I couldn't find any answer. Please anybody know about this issue can tell me why load is creeping on certain time. Will it be due to hardware issue? I have VPS with 12GB ram, 4 CPUs, 100GB Hard Drive and very light weight site with not much users.

Comment: Have you checked the Webserver Log? It usually shows all the connects, i often had on my own machines Spy-Bots trying to scan directories to exploit ect.

Comment: Yes I have checked everything on webserver log, error logs, slow query logs. But couldn't found anything...

Comment: Look at the Zombie processes, you have 8 of them, usually they are at zero and as far as my knowhow goes they only exist if there is not enough CPU to recycle them, now the question would be why you have such zombies (as i can see the php process is on defunct) so this means that somehow php is dieing, this is probably a good place to start